# Как округлять float числа в нужную сторону?

Tags: javascript

Возможно через отдельную функцию

```js
// 1 вариант, нужно округлять всегда в большую сторону
console.log( (0.564).toFixed(2) ) // 0.57
console.log( (120.117).toFixed(2) ) // 120.12
console.log( (120.117).toFixed(1) ) // 120.2
console.log('---');
// 2 вариант, нужно округлять всегда в меньшую сторону
console.log( (34.266).toFixed(2) ) // 34.26
console.log( (120.117).toFixed(2) ) // 120.11
console.log( (0.1817).toFixed(3) ) // 0.181

// PS.Округление всегда в меньшую сторону
function toFixed(number, fix) {
    return parseFloat(parseFloat(number).toFixed(fix + 1).slice(0, -1));
}
console.log( toFixed(34.266, 2) ) // 34.26
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133017/discussion-on-question-by-meru382---float----).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем я доволен результатом. Но с чего-то надо начинать:

```
const toFixedDown = (x, digits) => {
    const factor = 10 ** digits;
    return (Math.round(x * factor - 0.5) / factor).toFixed(digits);
};

const toFixedUp = (x, digits) => {
    const factor = 10 ** digits;
    return (Math.round(x * factor + 0.5) / factor).toFixed(digits);
};

const test = (x, digits) => console.log(
    x.toFixed(10),
    toFixedDown(x, digits),
    x.toFixed(digits),
    toFixedUp(x, digits),
);

test(0.564, 2);
test(120.117, 2);
test(120.117, 1);
test(34.266, 2);
test(0.1817, 3);
test(34.266, 2);
test(0.1, 2);
test(0.5, 2);
test(1, 2);
```

> ```
> $ node round.js
> 0.5640000000 0.56 0.56 0.57
> 120.1170000000 120.11 120.12 120.12
> 120.1170000000 120.1 120.1 120.2
> 34.2660000000 34.26 34.27 34.27
> 0.1817000000 0.181 0.182 0.182
> 34.2660000000 34.26 34.27 34.27
> 0.1000000000 0.10 0.10 0.11
> 0.5000000000 0.50 0.50 0.51
> 1.0000000000 1.00 1.00 1.01
> ```

Недоволен я последними двумя строчками. Кажется, если число точно представимо с заданной точностью, то хочется чтобы `toFixedDown` равнялось `toFixedUp`. Или я ошибаюсь?